# Property 'anything' does not exist on type 'Response<any, number>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express, mongoose

I am using typescript/express/mongoose stack. How do I override `Response` to include custom fieids in `res` in middlewares?

The problem is that when I assign `res.language` in the second function, I am modifying `Response`, so that it thinks that I am wrong. Removing `(req: Request, res, Response)` didn't help, because it assigns these classes by default.

Oh, yeah, the problem occurs on `res.language` field in both methods.

```js
// GET ONE
router.get('/:id', getLanguage, async (req: Request, res, Response) => {
  res.status(500).send(res.language);
});
```

```js
async function getLanguage(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  try {
    const language = await Language.findById(req.params.id);

    res.language = language;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

Solved with a help of [this](https://dev.to/kwabenberko/extend-express-s-request-object-with-typescript-declaration-merging-1nn5) by declaring

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Response {
      language: LanguageDoc;
    }
  }
}
```

Where `LanguageDoc` is an interface of `language`

Comment: `Request` *doesn't* have a `language` property. If you're adding it, you'd need e.g. `Request & { language: whatever }`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added `Request & {language: ...}` to the middleware, but now the assigning middleware in the first method complains that `No overload matches this call...` a lot of other words))

Comment: @jonrsharpe I even tried to write my own custom interface like ```interface custom extends Response {language: ...}```, but the same error with overloading occurs

Comment: @jonrsharpe and there is no problem with `Request`, I guess. Only `Response`